# Find and replace substrings in a Pandas dataframe ignore case

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

```
df.replace('Number', 'NewWord', regex=True)
```

how to replace `Number` or `number` or `NUMBER` with NewWord

Answer (score 6):

Same as you'd do with the standard regex, using the [`i` flag](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).

```
df = df.replace('(?i)Number', 'NewWord', regex=True)
```

Granted, `df.replace` is limiting in the sense that flags must be passed as part of the regex string (rather than flags). If this was using `str.replace`, you could've used `case=False` or `flags=re.IGNORECASE`.

Comment: Actually, I didn't think to pass flags via the pattern /shakesheadinshame.

Comment: @piRSquared I think yours is fine as long as OP only has the two cases to worry about.

Comment: Yeah, I like yours because it captures the spirit of what I guessed they intended.  sacul as well.

Comment: Is it possible to use flags if I'm using lists to replace. For eg.: ```df = df[col].replace('(?i)['No, Number'], ['NewWord'])```?

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `case=False` in `str.replace`.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['this is a Number', 'and another NuMBer', 'number']})

>>> df
                  col
0    this is a Number
1  and another NuMBer
2              number

df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('Number', 'NewWord', case=False)

>>> df
                   col
0    this is a NewWord
1  and another NewWord
2              NewWord
```

**[Edit]**: In the case of having multiple columns you are looking for your substring in, you can select all columns with `object` dtypes, and apply the above solution to them. Example:

```
>>> df
                  col                col2  col3
0    this is a Number  numbernumbernumber     1
1  and another NuMBer                   x     2
2              number                   y     3

str_columns = df.select_dtypes('object').columns

df[str_columns] = (df[str_columns]
                   .apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('Number', 'NewWord', case=False)))

>>> df
                   col                   col2  col3
0    this is a NewWord  NewWordNewWordNewWord     1
1  and another NewWord                      x     2
2              NewWord                      y     3
```

Comment: This is the right answer assuming it is just one column OP is worried about, so +1. In the event this is to be done for multiple columns, however, you may want to either 1) apply str.replace or 2) stack + str.replace.

Comment: True, thanks, I've included an example for that scenario. The issue with the stack method is that it will change the numeric dtypes

Answer (score 3):

Brutish.  This only works if the whole string is either `'Number'` or `'NUMBER'`.  It will not replace those within a larger string.  And of course, it is limited to just those two words.

```
df.replace(['Number', 'NUMBER'], 'NewWord')
```

---

More Brute Force
If it wasn't obvious enough, this is far inferior to @coldspeed's answer

```
import re

df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub('number', 'NewWord', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

Or with a cue from @coldspeed's answer

```
df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub('(?i)number', 'NewWord', x))
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work if the text you're looking to convert is in specific columns of your dataframe:

```
    df['COL_n'] = df['COL_n'].str.lower() 
    df['COL_n'] = df['COL_n'].replace('number', 'NewWord', regex=True)
```