# Replace entire string based on regex match

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe of email address and wanted to replace all the .edu emails with "Edu". I came up with an highly inefficient way of doing it but there has to be a better way of doing it. This is how I do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
inp = [{'c1':10, 'c2':'gedua.com'},   {'c1':11,'c2':'wewewe.Edu'},   {'c1':12,'c2':'wewewe.edu.ney'}]
dfn = pd.DataFrame(inp)

for index, row in dfn.iterrows():
    try:
        if len(re.search('\.edu', row['c2']).group(0)) > 1:
            dfn.c2[index] = 'Edu'
            print('Education')
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: So you only want to change the last e-mail, even though the second e-mail ends with `.Edu`? Or do you also want to change all variations of .edu regardless of capitalization?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry I wrote ".Edu". It is ".edu" that I want to replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `str.contains` for case insensitive selection, and assignment with `loc`.

```
dfn.loc[dfn.c2.str.contains(r'\.Edu', case=False), 'c2'] = 'Edu'    
dfn

   c1         c2
0  10  gedua.com
1  11        Edu
2  12        Edu
```

If it's only the emails *ending* with `.edu` you want to replace, then

```
dfn.loc[dfn.c2.str.contains(r'\.Edu$', case=False), 'c2'] = 'Edu'
```

Or, as suggested by piR,

```
dfn.loc[dfn.c2.str.endswith('.Edu'), 'c2'] = 'Edu'
```

```
dfn

   c1              c2
0  10       gedua.com
1  11             Edu
2  12  wewewe.edu.ney
```

Comment: Also, `dfn.loc[dfn.c2.str.endswith('.Edu'), 'c2']`

Answer (score 2):

### `replace`

```
dfn.replace('^.*\.Edu$', 'Edu', regex=True)

   c1              c2
0  10       gedua.com
1  11             Edu
2  12  wewewe.edu.ney
```

The pattern `'^.*\.Edu$'` says grab everything from the beginning of the string to the point where we find `'.Edu'` followed by the end of the string, then replace that whole thing with `'Edu'`

---

### Column specific

You may want to limit the scope to just a column (or columns).  You can do that by passing a dictionary to `replace` where the outer key specifies the column and the dictionary value specifies what is to be replaced.

```
dfn.replace({'c2': {'^.*\.Edu$': 'Edu'}}, regex=True)

   c1              c2
0  10       gedua.com
1  11             Edu
2  12  wewewe.edu.ney
```

---

### Case insensitive [[thx @coldspeed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51864376/2336654)]

`pandas.DataFrame.replace` does not have a case flag.  But you can imbed it in the pattern with `'(?i)'`

```
dfn.replace({'c2': {'(?i)^.*\.edu$': 'Edu'}}, regex=True)

   c1              c2
0  10       gedua.com
1  11             Edu
2  12  wewewe.edu.ney
```